# Add different footer on every page in print preview

Tags: jquery, html, css, printing

I have page that contains lessons,I want to print this page and i want to add footer to every page contains (current lesson name ,current lesson created date) to every page in print mode.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.footer {
    display:none;
}
@media print {
.Lesson
{
page-break-after:always;
}
.footer {
    display:Block;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="lesson1" class="Lesson">
lesson text
<div id="print-footer print-footer1" class="footer">footer 1 content</div>
</div>
<div id="lesson2" class="Lesson">
lesson text
<div id="print-footer print-footer2" class="footer">footer 2 content</div>
</div>
<div id="lesson3" class="Lesson">
lesson text
<div id="print-footer print-footer3" class="footer">footer 3 content</div>
</div>
<div id="lesson4" class="Lesson">
lesson text
<div id="print-footer print-footer4" class="footer">footer 4 content</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can add fixed footer but can not add different footer on every page in print preview.

Comment: Is it possible to print a different footer on every page?

Comment: @OllyHodgson, Please Check my code

Comment: @AmirSalah Part of the problem could be `id="print-footer print-footer1"`, which is invalid. `class` is a space-separated list, not `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible option in css. You need to use some other language for dynamic variation depend on your requirements or use jquery.

Here the html

```
 <span>Hello</span>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
```

Here the jquery

```
 var htmlStr = $('span').html();
  $('div').text(htmlStr);
```

DEMO: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TvmxD/)

Comment: Is it possible to print a different footer on every page?

Comment: May be. I did not try this method. You can try. But class name should be in same.

Comment: I want it in print mode not in normal Html preview

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great method but it would work. You can add all the footer DIVs you require to every page like so:

```
<div class="print-footer print-footer1">footer 1 content</div>
<div class="print-footer print-footer2">footer 2 content</div>
<div class="print-footer print-footer3">footer 3 content</div>
<div class="print-footer print-footer4">footer 4 content</div>
<div class="print-footer print-footer5">footer 5 content</div>
```

Then hide them using CSS:

```
.print-footer {
    display:none;
}
```

Then add a class to the BODY tag on each page like so:

```
<body class="lesson1">
<body class="lesson2">
<body class="lesson3">
<body class="lesson4">
<body class="lesson5">
```

And show the correct footer when printing using that BODY class:

```
@media print {

body.lesson1 .print-footer1 {
    display:block;
}

body.lesson2 .print-footer2 {
        display:block;
}

body.lesson3 .print-footer3 {
        display:block;
}

body.lesson4 .print-footer4 {
        display:block;
}

body.lesson5 .print-footer5 {
        display:block;
}

}
```

Comment: I want to add footer in bottom of page and want to print all lessons at one time.

Answer (score 0):

I've re-read your question properly, and tried the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Print footer test</title>
        <style>
        .print-footer {
            display: none;
        }
        @media print {
            /* put the page-break after the footer! */
            .print-footer {
                display:block;
                page-break-after: always;
            }
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="lesson" id="lesson1">lesson 1 content</div>
        <div class="print-footer">footer 1 content</div>
        <div class="lesson" id="lesson2">lesson 2 content</div>
        <div class="print-footer">footer 2 content</div>
        <div class="lesson" id="lesson3">lesson 3 content</div>
        <div class="print-footer">footer 3 content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works in print preview on the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE10 on Windows. Basically, I'm showing a print-footer in print mode, and making sure the `page-break-after: always;` comes *after the footer*, not the lesson.

Note some older versions of Internet Explorer (and no doubt other browsers) don't support print CSS very well, especially things like `page-break-after`, so make sure you test thoroughly!

(Also, make sure you [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/), otherwise you can't blame the browser for getting things wrong. You're missing a `DOCTYPE`, a `<title>` and your `id` attributes are invalid - they cannot contain whitespace.)